# Can't add product into Cart

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, mern

Unable to add product into the cart although, the url is getting changed, it showing two errors in the console, cant understand what is wrong.

http://localhost:3000/cart/636d4264ff92e60977f3bb4a?qt=3
636d4264ff92e60977f3bb4a = productID  and  qt=3 quantity

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dlda.png)

here are my files

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, ListGroup, Image, Form, Button, Card } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { addToCart, removeFromCart } from '../actions/cartActions'

const CartScreen = ({match, history}) => {
  
  const {id} = useParams();
  //const productId = match.params.id

  const location = useLocation();

  const qty = location.search ? Number (location.search.split('=') [1]) : 1

  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const navigate = useNavigate()

  const cart = useSelector((state) => state.cart)
  const { cartItems } = cart

  useEffect(() => {
    if(id){
      //useEffect  working fine
      dispatch(addToCart(id,qty))
    }else{
      //console.log('useEffect error')
    }
  }, [dispatch, id, qty])

  const removeFromCartHandler = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeFromCart(id))
  }

  const chechoutHandler = () => {
    navigate('/login?redirect=/shipping')
  }
  
  return (
  <Row>
    <Col md={8}>
      <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
      
      { cartItems && cartItems.length === 0 ? (
        <Message> Your cart is empty <Link to='/'>Go Back</Link></Message> 
      ) : (
        <ListGroup variant='flush'> 
            {cartItems.map(item => (
              <ListGroup.Item key={item.product}>
                <Row>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Image src={item.image} alt={item.name} className="cartItemPhoto" flude rounded />
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={3}>
                    <Link to={`/product/${item.product}`}>{item.name}</Link>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>₹{item.price}</Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Form.Control 
                      as='select' 
                      value={item.qty} 
                      onChange={(e)=> dispatch(addToCart(item.product,Number(e.target.value)))}
                    >

                    {[...Array(item.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                        <option key={x+1} value={x + 1}>
                            { x + 1 }
                        </option>
                    ))}

                    </Form.Control>
                  </Col>
                  <Col md={2}>
                    <Button type='button' varient='ligth' onClick={() => removeFromCartHandler(item.product)} >
                      <i className='fas fa-trash'></i>
                    </Button>
                  </Col>
                </Row>
              </ListGroup.Item>
            ))}
          </ListGroup>
      )}
      
    </Col>
    <Col md={4}>
      <Card>
        <ListGroup varient = 'flush'>
          <ListGroup.Item>
            <h2>Subtotal ({cartItems.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item.qty,0)}) items</h2>
            ₹{cartItems.reduce((acc,item)=>acc+item.qty * item.price,0).toFixed(2)}
          </ListGroup.Item>
          <ListGroup>
            <Button type='button' className='btn-block' disabled={cartItems.length === 0} onClick={chechoutHandler}> 
              Proceed To Checkout
            </Button>
          </ListGroup>
        </ListGroup>
      </Card>
    </Col>

  </Row>
  )
}

export default CartScreen
```

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { Link, useParams} from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import {Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import { listProductDetails, createProductReview  } from '../actions/productActions'
import {  useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
//import products from '../../../backend/data/products.js'
//import axios from 'axios'

import { PRODUCT_CREATE_REVIEW_RESET } from '../constants/productConstants'


const ProductScreen = ({ match}) => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    //const product = products.find((p) => p._id === id);

    const [qty, setQty] = useState(1)
    const [rating, setRating] = useState(0)
    const [comment, setComment] = useState('')

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
    const { loading, error, product } = productDetails

    //console.log(product)
    // reviews aasche sudhu

    const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
    const { userInfo } = userLogin

    const productReviewCreate = useSelector((state) => state.productReviewCreate)
    const {
        success: successProductReview,
        loading: loadingProductReview,
        error: errorProductReview,
    } = productReviewCreate

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(successProductReview){
            alert('Review Submitted!')
            setRating(0)
            setComment('')
            dispatch({type: PRODUCT_CREATE_REVIEW_RESET})
        }
        dispatch(listProductDetails(id))
    }, [dispatch, id, successProductReview])
    
   //if(!product) return null;

   // return ( <div>{product.name}</div> );

   const history = useNavigate()

    const addToCartHandler = () =>{
        history(`/cart/${id}?qt=${qty}`)
    }

    const submitHandler = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        dispatch(
          createProductReview(id, {
            rating,
            comment,
          })
        )
    }

    //console.log(product)

   return (
    <>
        <Link className='btn btn-outline-primary' to='/'>
            Go Back
        </Link>
        { loading ? ( 
           <Loader/> 
        ): error ? ( 
           <Message variant='danger'> {error} </Message> 
        ) : (
            <>
            <Row>
                <Col md={6}>
                    {/* src={product.image}       changed to ->         {`${window.location.origin}/${product.image.name}`} */}
                    <Image src= {product.image} alt={product.name} fluid/>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <ListGroup variant='flust'>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            <h3>{product.name}</h3>
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                          {/* 
                            <Rating 
                                value={product.rating.toString()} 
                                text={product.numReviews}
                            />
                          */}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            Price: ₹{product.price}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            Description: {product.description}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Col>
                <Col md={3}>
                    <Card>
                        <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                        Price:
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        <strong>₹{product.price}</strong>
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Row>
                                    <Col>
                                        Status:
                                    </Col>
                                    <Col>
                                        {product.countInStock>0 ? 'In Stock' : 'Out Of Stock'}
                                    </Col>
                                </Row>
                            </ListGroup.Item>




                            { product.countInStock > 0 && (
                                <ListGroup.Item>
                                    <Row>
                                        <Col>Qty</Col>
                                        <Col>
                                            <Form.Control 
                                                as='select' 
                                                value={qty} 

                                                onChange={(e)=>setQty(e.target.value)}
                                            >

                                            {[...Array(product.countInStock).keys()].map((x) => (
                                                <option key={x+1} value={x + 1}>
                                                    { x + 1 }
                                                </option>
                                            ))}
                                            </Form.Control>
                                        </Col>
                                    </Row>
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            )}




                            <ListGroup.Item>
                                <Button 
                                    onClick={addToCartHandler}
                                    className='btn btn-success btn-block btn-wd' 
                                    type='button'
                                    disabled={product.countInStock===0}
                                >
                                    Add To Cart
                                </Button>
                            </ListGroup.Item>

                        </ListGroup>
                    </Card>
                </Col>
            </Row>

            <Col md={6}>
              <h2>Reviews</h2>
              {product.reviews.length === 0 && <Message>No Reviews</Message>}
              <ListGroup variant='flush'>
                {product.reviews.map((review) => (
                  <ListGroup.Item key={review._id}>
                    <strong>{review.name}</strong>
                    <Rating value={review.rating} />
                    <p>{review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}</p>
                    <p>{review.comment}</p>
                  </ListGroup.Item>
                ))}
                <ListGroup.Item>
                  <h2>Write a Customer Review</h2>
                  {successProductReview && (
                    <Message variant='success'>
                      Review submitted successfully
                    </Message>
                  )}
                  {loadingProductReview && <Loader />}
                  {errorProductReview && (
                    <Message variant='danger'>{errorProductReview}</Message>
                  )}
                  {userInfo ? (
                    <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
                      <Form.Group controlId='rating'>
                        <Form.Label>Rating</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                          as='select'
                          value={rating}
                          onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                        >
                          <option value=''>Select...</option>
                          <option value='1'>1 - Poor</option>
                          <option value='2'>2 - Fair</option>
                          <option value='3'>3 - Good</option>
                          <option value='4'>4 - Very Good</option>
                          <option value='5'>5 - Excellent</option>
                        </Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Form.Group controlId='comment'>
                        <Form.Label>Comment</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control
                          as='textarea'
                          row='3'
                          value={comment}
                          onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                        ></Form.Control>
                      </Form.Group>
                      <Button
                        disabled={loadingProductReview}
                        type='submit'
                        variant='primary'
                      >
                        Submit
                      </Button>
                    </Form>
                  ) : (
                    <Message>
                      Please <Link to='/login'>sign in</Link> to write a review{' '}
                    </Message>
                  )}
                </ListGroup.Item>
              </ListGroup>
            </Col>

            </>


        )}
        
    </>
   )

}

// Form.Control e add chilo, onChange{(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
/*
  <Form.Control 
    as='select' 
    value={qty} 

    onChange{(e) => setQty(e.target.value)}
  >

  // lec 32

*/


export default ProductScreen
```

```
import axios from 'axios'
import { 
  CART_ADD_ITEM, 
  CART_REMOVE_ITEM, 
  CART_SAVE_SHIPING_ADDRESS,
  CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD
} from '../constants/cartConstants'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'




export const addToCart = (id, qty) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
    const {id} = useParams();
    //console.log(`id working = ${id}`)
    const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${id}`)
    //console.log(`data = ${data}`)
    dispatch({
      type: CART_ADD_ITEM,
      payload: {
        product: data._id,
        name: data.name,
        image: data.image,
        price: data.price,
        countInStock: data.countInStock,
        qty,
      },
    })
  
    localStorage.setItem('cartItems', JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}


export const removeFromCart = (id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({
        type: CART_REMOVE_ITEM,
        payload: id
    })

    localStorage.setItem('cartItems',JSON.stringify(getState().cart.cartItems))
}

export const saveShippingAdderss = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
      type: CART_SAVE_SHIPING_ADDRESS,
      payload: data,
  })

  localStorage.setItem('shippingAddress',JSON.stringify(data))
}


export const savePaymentMethod = (data) => (dispatch) => {
  dispatch({
      type: CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD,
      payload: data,
  })

  localStorage.setItem('paymentMethod',JSON.stringify(data))
}
```

```
import { CART_ADD_ITEM, CART_REMOVE_ITEM, CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD, CART_SAVE_SHIPING_ADDRESS } from '../constants/cartConstants.js'
import { PRODUCT_DETAILS_REQUEST, PRODUCT_LIST_REQUEST } from '../constants/productConstants.js'

export const cartReducer = ( 
    state = { cartItems: [], shippingAddress: {} }, action) => {
        //console.log(`action.type line on 6 = ${action.type}`)
    switch(action.type){
        case CART_ADD_ITEM:
            //console.log(`CART_ADD_ITEM 3333 = ${action.type}`)
            
            const item = action.payload

            const existItem = state.cartItems.find( (x) => x.product === item.product)

            if(existItem){
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: state.cartItems.map ((x) => 
                        x.product === existItem.product ? item : x
                    ),
                }
            } else {
                return {
                    ...state,
                    cartItems: [...state.cartItems, item],
                }
            } 
        case CART_REMOVE_ITEM:
           return {
                ...state,
                cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((x) => x.product !==action.payload),
           } 
        case CART_SAVE_SHIPING_ADDRESS:
            return {
                ...state,
                shippingAddress: action.payload,
            } 
        case CART_SAVE_PAYMENT_METHOD:
            return {
                ...state,
                paymentMethod: action.payload,
            } 
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

I want to resolve the error so that I can add products to my cart. Thank you

Comment: The Error is telling you that you can't use `useParams()` inside your `addToCart` function, because it's not a React component. Can't you use the `id` which is already in your function call?

Comment: Just remove `const {id} = useParams();` from `addToCart`